# Multipart request spring does not bind file data

Tags: android, spring, spring-mvc, multipart, okhttp

I'm having a problem with a controller that i wrote in order to upload photos to a server.

the Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "photos", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Response uploadPhoto(@RequestPart PhotoMetaData data, 
                            @RequestParam String localName,
                            @RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile file, 
                            HttpServletRequest request) {

    log.info("@uploadPhoto > ip of request: " + request.getRemoteAddr() + ", metaData: " + data);

    return photosService.storePhoto(data, file, localName);
}
```

problem is that `file` is null but when inspecting `request` parameter the request clearly has 3 multipart params, each also has it's supposed contentType but file is a long string.

[image: debug capturing]

Android app is calling this code. i'm using OkHttp in order to build the multipart request. code:

```
MediaType jsonMediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder()
             .type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)                                                                     
             .addPart(Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"data\""),                                         
              RequestBody.create(jsonMediaType, photoMetaDataStr))                                                                                                     
             .addPart(Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"localName\""),
              RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), localName.getPath()))
             .addPart(Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\""),
              RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), new File(localName.getPath())))
                                                    .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).post(requestBody).build();

    final Response response = client.newCall(request)
                                   .execute();
```

------ EDIT ------------

relevant beans:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {

    return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
}
```

---- EDIT 2 -----
after changing the controller signature  such that file is required i'm getting an exception:

---- EDIT 3------
After extensive testing i've noticed that the problem is probably the way i'm using okHttp in order to send the multipart request to the server. using Postman client, the call was successful

```
error with request org.springframework.web.multipart.support.DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest@3d854606
org.springframework.web.multipart.support
.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present.
```

Thanks for your time and help

Roy

Comment: Try `@RequestPart` instead of `@RequestParam` for the `MultipartFile` parameter.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your response. already tried every possible combination including changing `@RequestParam` to `@RequestPart`. didn't work

Comment: If it doesn't work your configuration is flawed. The fact that everything is a `String` or `String[]` isn't strange as that is how the web works, the parameters are converted afterwards. However it should be a `@RequestPart` and not a `@RequestParam` the conversion from `String` to request type is handled quite differently between the two. Make sure you compile with debug information else try `@RequestPart(value="file"), required=false)` for debugging you could try and make `required` true (and see what error is being spit out).

Comment: @M.Deinum i'm also guessing that something is flawed with my configuration but can't really understand what, there is only one bean (for what i understand) that needs to be defined for multipart request and i took care of it. i did what u suggested and added the required part to the file but the exception is...not a big help /-:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i was able to solve the problem by just adding to the request the Content-Transfer-Encoding header.

```
RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBuilder().type(MultipartBuilder.FORM)
                                                    .addPart(Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"data\""),
                                                            RequestBody.create(jsonMediaType, GsonInstance.getInstance()
                                                                                                          .toJson(photoMetaData)))
                                                    .addPart(Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"localName\"", "Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary"),
                                                            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), new File(localName.getPath())))
                                                    .build();
```

I'm not sure why it's matter. for my understanding the default transfer encoding is binary when the contentType is image. maybe it's a minor bug with okHttp?